# Acceptance Test with MockMultipartFile, and HttpMessageConversionException occurs

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I tried AcceptanceTest with MockMultipartFile class in springboot and `HttpMessageConversionException` occurs.

and I saw many code work with File Object but as you see my dto contains MultipartFile..

could you know me why It doesn't works? and How to fix it?

It is jackson converting error, so I check all of get~ method and
I tried for making CustomMultipartFile and override getInputStream method and attach `@JsonIgnore` 
but it make another error and doesn't work

```java
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile["inputStream"])

    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:417)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:393)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:373)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:733)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.exchange(TestRestTemplate.java:774)
    at com.mappractice.demo.acceptanceTest.AcceptanceTest.sendFile(AcceptanceTest.java:51)
    at com.mappractice.demo.acceptanceTest.ImageAcceptanceTest.이미지_생성_API_성공(ImageAcceptanceTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile["inputStream"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:313)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)
    ... 45 more
```

**TEST CODE**

```java
public class ImageAcceptanceTest extends AcceptanceTest {
    private static final String API_IMAGE_URI = "/api/image";

    private static MockMultipartFile content;
    private static Image image;
    private static PositionedImageDTO positionedImageDTO;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        content = new MockMultipartFile("file",
                "ded.png",
                "image/png",
                "datdedadsdwdssdwa".getBytes()
        );
        image = new Image(1L, "테스트 이미지", "12kl312nlk3".getBytes(), new Location("12.1234567", "12.1234566"));
        positionedImageDTO = new PositionedImageDTO("테스트 이미지", content, "12.1234567", "12.1234566");
    }

    @Test
    public void image_create_API_success() {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.add("fileName", "테스트 이미지");
        parameters.add("file", content);
        parameters.add("xIndex", "123");
        parameters.add("yIndex", "454");

        ResponseEntity<Image> responseEntity = sendFile(API_IMAGE_URI, parameters, Image.class);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getName()).isEqualTo("테스트 이미지");
    }

...
```

**Controller CODE**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/image")
public class ApiImageController {

    ...

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Image> create(@ModelAttribute PositionedImageDTO positionedImageDTO){
        Image image = imageService.create(positionedImageDTO);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setLocation(URI.create("/api/image/"+image.getId()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(image, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    ...

}
```

**DTO CODE**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class PositionedImageDTO {

    @NotEmpty
    private String fileName;

    @NotEmpty
    private MultipartFile file;

    @NotNull
    private String xIndex;

    @NotNull
    private String yIndex;

    public PositionedImageDTO(String fileName, MultipartFile file, String xIndex, String yIndex) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.file = file;
        this.xIndex = xIndex;
        this.yIndex = yIndex;
    }

    public String getExtentionFormat() {
        return "." + file.getContentType().split("/")[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: The content should be the actuqal content NOT a `MockMultipartFile`. Use either  one of the `Resource` implementations from Spring or an `InputStream`.